# Vectorized version of which in R?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector

I want to run this loop:

```
   householdnums=numeric()
    for(i in 1:length(households)){
        hh = households[i]
        householdnums = c(householdnums,which(hhlist==hh))
    }
```

Where households and hhlist is a large vector.  The problem is that households has duplicates of elements in hhlist, and I need to preserve the ordering.  For example.

```
hhlist = c(1,2,3,4,5,6, 8)

households = c(1,2,1,1,4,5,6,8)

householdnums should be:

householdnums
[1] 1 2 1 1 4 6 6 7
```

Comment: I didn't understand how your householdnums should be  `1 2 1 1 4 6 6 7`

Comment: Do you want `match` : eg `match(households, hhlist)`

Comment: Ouch, my head! :p OP, I think we need clarification on what you're asking / doing here! Thx

Comment: `which` is vectorized.

Comment: Match is exactly what I want!  Can you post and I will best answer you

Comment: Hi @robertevansanders; please feel free to answer your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

match : eg match(households, hhlist)